# Text not appearing after figure and is forced to start from new page

Tags: floats, multicol

I have the following situation.

I am using `multicols` and inserting `figure` inside them. I have two of those. However, I want my text to continue appearing after the second `multicol` but it is always moving to a new page.

Below is the scenario that I now have:

[image]

and I want to reach this scenario:

[image]

I tried using the

`\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother`

to push the first figure to the upper part of the page, and I succeeded with that, but the second figure always had a big gap between itself and the first image.

I tried

`\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fpbot}{500pt}
\makeatother`

to get the second figure directly under the first one and it worked, but the remaining text continued showing up on the next page.

Below is my code.

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{multicols}{3}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img1.png}
         \caption{caption1}
         \label{fig:}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img2.png}
        \caption{caption2}
        \label{fig:}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img3.png}
        \caption{caption3}
        \label{fig:}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{caption4}
    \label{fig:label1}
\end{figure*}
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{3}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img4.png}
        \caption{caption5}
        \label{fig:}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img5.png}
       \caption{caption6}
        \label{fig:}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img6.png}
        \caption{caption7}
        \label{fig:}
    \end{subfigure}
   \caption{caption8}
   \label{fig:label2}
\end{figure*}
\end{multicols}

\FloatBarrier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide a test file or show the definition of the syntax you showed, but I guess it is `subcaption` package syntax. This variant produces the desired format as far as I understand it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol,subcaption,graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}



\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image.png}
         \caption{caption1}
         \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image.png}
        \caption{caption2}
        \label{fig:aa}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image.png}
        \caption{caption3}
        \label{fig:aaa}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{caption4}
    \label{fig:label1}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image.png}
        \caption{caption5}
        \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image.png}
       \caption{caption6}
        \label{fig:bb}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image.png}
        \caption{caption7}
        \label{fig:bbb}
    \end{subfigure}
   \caption{caption8}
   \label{fig:label2}
\end{figure*}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```